# I want to use tensorflow to detect objects in images how can I go about this

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection

I have trained a tensorflow object detection model and can detect objects in images. But I want run the model on videos.

So far the only method I can find is to convert the video into individual frames. Is there a way to just run it as the video plays.

Comment: Video is esentially a slideshow of individual images. You can show the original image and the output of your model at the same time, if that's you're asking.

Comment: @doneforaiur This is basically poc for real time detection with a camera. Ideally would run model in real time on monitor and just play video if that is possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible but it's not a direct question. If you have a specific question about taking realtime camera data and processing/displaying it I'd suggest opening a new question. You can also check this; https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/object-detection-using-tensorflow/ Hope it helps.